# Why does a CSRF token need a timeout? (ZF2)

Tags: php, zend-framework2, csrf

This is mostly a generic question, but I am specifically working with ZF2.  I'd like to understand exactly how the CSRF token works and what determines how long a TTL (timeout) I should have on it.

I understand that it is generating a unique hash for each form that is rendered and checking that hash on submission of the form, but what does it check it against, is it keeping a copy of the hash on the server side as well?  Is it single use? I'm guessing not since I can re-submit the same form multiple times (i.e. hit refresh on the page that results from the form post).  But, it must be specific to that form and my current session, right?

Why does it need to time-out?  Currently, I somewhat frequently have pages where I submit, or re-submit, the form after 5 mins (the default ZF2 CSRF timeout) and I get the CSRF error message.  This is an annoyance for legitimate user interaction.  Should I increase or remove the timeout?  What's the security trade off?

I'm hoping by having a better understanding of the mechanics of ZF2's CSRF system I'll be better informed for decisions like this.  Also, what are your recommended CSRF configuration options?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://owasp.org/index.php/CSRF_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: It's a security feature to prevent hijacking of stale CSRF tokens; ensuing that the given token can only be validated within that timeframe. I would recommend increasing the time-out rather than removing it.

Comment: The cheat sheet has moved: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet